# Prevent View From Sliding When Keyboard Switches To Date Picker

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, uikeyboard

In my app I have a UIView that holds three textfields:

First Name, Last Name, Date of Birth.

The name fields are side by side on one "line" and the DOB field is on the "line" below it.

When the keyboard is opened or closed, the view controller slides up or down to make sure the fields don't get covered. I can switch from first name to last name without additional sliding as they Keyboard stays open. However, Date of Birth is set to show a UIDatePicker instead of a keyboard. When the user moves from either name field to the Date field, the Keyboard switches to a Date Picker but doesn't perform the "keyboardWillHide" function. It will, however, perform the "keyboardWillShow" function for the new Date Picker, thus sliding the View Controller up again.

Because of this issue, any content at the top of the page will scroll out of view without any way to get it back, except for relaunching the app, or resetting the VC's origin coords on viewWillAppear/Disappear.

Here's what my code looks like at the moment for the sliding:

```
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
                kbHeight = keyboardSize.height
                self.animateTextField(true)
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.animateTextField(false)
    }

    func animateTextField(up: Bool) {
            var movementDistance = 80
            var movementDuration = 0.3
            var movement = CGFloat(up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance)
            UIView.beginAnimations("anim", context: nil)
            UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
            UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)
            self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
            UIView.commitAnimations()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a tracking var to tell when the keyboard has been open and closed. That way the sliding function only performs when the condition is met.

My new code for the animation function is:

```
    func animateTextField(up: Bool) {
        if(up) {
            if(!keyboardIsOpen) {
                var movementDistance = -80
                var movementDuration = 0.3
                var movement = CGFloat(movementDistance)
                UIView.beginAnimations("anim", context: nil)
                UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
                UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)
                self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
                UIView.commitAnimations()
                keyboardIsOpen = true
            }
        }
        else {
            if(keyboardIsOpen) {
                var movementDistance = 80
                var movementDuration = 0.3
                var movement = CGFloat(movementDistance)
                UIView.beginAnimations("anim", context: nil)
                UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
                UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)
                self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
                UIView.commitAnimations()
                keyboardIsOpen = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Simple.